# How to change the data in a ListView of one Activity from other Activity

Tags: android, listview

I have seen few question on SOF, but neither of them helped.

In my application I have a List of users which can be accessed by clicking friends of a user. The flow is:

> 1. Go to my profile
> 2. Click on my friends to go to an Activity which has list of users(my friends)
> 3. Click on any of the listView Item takes to that user's profile
> 4. From that profile I can see that user's friends list the same way as mine.

The problem is all these listView items have a button to `add as friend` which makes me and that user as friend in that list(like follow changes to following in twitter) now I come back through the backstack, and somewhere in one of the previous listViews that user is present for whom the button is still `add as friend`.

How to change the button(a flag in my adapter data) for that user in all the ListViews?

Comment: Try to define your Items static global and also your listview. Or use Bundle and putextras

Comment: I cannot send back data to an Activity which is 5 steps away in the backstack. Actually I don't even know which ListView to change. ALso static data wont work because there are multiple instances of the Activity which has the List

Comment: if global variables are impossible then it's not suitable to use but onresume events at those activities just recreate list from DB or wherever you want.

Comment: How do you store friend's list for each user? Are you using a database? Also, am I right by assuming that each of the steps you mentioned starts a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Interface` to send events back to the activity and update the list or database when the event is received.

Interfaces are ways of passing messages to "the outer world". Just look at a simple `button onClickListener`. You basically call a `setOnClickListener(this)` on the button and implement `onClickListener`, which is an `interface` here. Whenever the button is clicked, you get an event in `onClick`. It is the safest way to pass messages between activities without the need of intents ( which according to me is a huge pain in the ... ) Here is an example:

Example:

```
class A extends Activity implements EventInterface{

    public A(){

        //set a listener. (Do not forget it!!!)
        //You can call it wherever you want; 
        //just make sure that it is called before you need something out of it.
        //safest place is onCreate.
        setEventInterfaceListener( A.this );

    }      

    //this method will be automatically added once you implement EventInterface.
    void eventFromClassB(int event){

         //you receive events here.
         //Check the "event" variable to see which event it is.

    }         

}


class B{

    //Interface logic
    public interface EventInterface{
        public static int BUTTON_CLICKED = 1;

        void eventFromClassB(int event);
    }
    static EventInterface events;

    public static void setEventInterfaceListener(EventInterface listener) {
        events = listener;
    }

    private void dispatchEvent(int trigger) {
        if (events != null) {
            events.eventFromClassB(trigger);
        }
    }

    //Interface ends

    void yourMethod(){

       //Call this whenever you want to send an event.
       dispatchEvent( BUTTON_CLICKED );

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code or a link to what you recommended.